# how to fix preg_match() unknown modifier '?' in localeconv()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

the problem s in the `'decimal_point' => string '/'`

but did anyone have a good solution to fix it?

**the error**:

```
  preg_match() unknown modifier '?'
```

**the function :**

```php
     * @param   string  $str    input string
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public static function numeric($str)
    {
        // Get the decimal point for the current locale
        list($decimal) = array_values(localeconv());

        // A lookahead is used to make sure the string contains at least one digit (before or after the decimal point)

         return (bool) preg_match('/^-?+(?=.*[0-9])[09]*+'.preg_quote($decimal).'?+[0-9]*+$/D', (string) $str); 
}
```

**it's localeconv() dump :**

```
array (size=18)
  'decimal_point' => string '/' (length=1)
  'thousands_sep' => string ',' (length=1)
  'int_curr_symbol' => string 'IRR' (length=3)
  'currency_symbol' => string 'ريال' (length=8)
  'mon_decimal_point' => string '/' (length=1)
  'mon_thousands_sep' => string ',' (length=1)
  'positive_sign' => string '' (length=0)
  'negative_sign' => string '-' (length=1)
  'int_frac_digits' => int 2
  'frac_digits' => int 2
  'p_cs_precedes' => int 0
  'p_sep_by_space' => int 0
  'n_cs_precedes' => int 0
  'n_sep_by_space' => int 0
  'p_sign_posn' => int 3
  'n_sign_posn' => int 3
  'grouping' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 3
  'mon_grouping' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 3
```

the relate issue on github
[koseven/issues #351](https://github.com/koseven/koseven/issues/351)

Comment: Could you post the full question with the code sample on Stack Overflow instead of linking to GitHub, please?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `/` as the delimiter in your regexp, pass it to the [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function as well, as the second parameter:

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^-?+(?=.*[0-9])[09]*+' . preg_quote($decimal, '/') . '?+[0-9]*+$/D', (string) $str);
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Quote from the manual:

> Note that / is not a special regular expression character.
>
> [...]
>
> **delimiter**
>   If the optional delimiter is specified, it will also be escaped. This is useful for escaping the delimiter that is required
>   by the PCRE functions. The / is the most commonly used delimiter.

Comment: so if the `decimal_point` have another character can it cuz a problem ???

Comment: Absolutely not!

Comment: To summarize: it is possible for you to use arbitrary characters as delimiter in regex e.g. `preg_match('!foo!')` or `preg_match('@foo@')`. `preg_quote` must be told which delimiter you used in the regex so that it can escape it **if necessary**. The `@` character for example does not need to be escaped but if it was used as delimiter that it must be escaped.